# Is there a way to exit or break a switch statement in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, switch-statement, exit, break

For example:

```
Select Case (x)
    Case 1
        If ... Then
            ***Break***
        End If

        Response.Write( ... )

    Case Else
        Response.Write( ... )
End Select
```

Comment: This is a VBScript question, not ASP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Select Case` is not broken from. Neither is `If`.

Syntax:

> **Select Case** testexpression
>
> [**Case** expressionlist-n
>
> [statements-n]] . . .
>
> [**Case Else** expressionlist-n
>
> [elsestatements-n]]
>
> **End Select**

[Source](http://ns7.webmasters.com/caspdoc/html/vbscript_select_case_statement.htm)

VBScript's equivalent of break is `Exit`. And it's present in the following forms:

```
Exit Do
Exit For
Exit Function
Exit Sub
```

[Source](http://ns7.webmasters.com/caspdoc/html/vbscript_exit_statement.htm)

Answer (score 3):

To jump in VBScript, you'll have to `Exit` a loop (or a Sub/Function, (c) @Andrevinsky):

```
Option Explicit

Dim i
For i = 1 To 3
    Do ' Jumper Do
        Select Case i
          Case 1, 2
            WScript.Echo i, "A"
            If i = 2 Then
               WScript.Echo i, "B"
               Exit Do
            End If
            WScript.Echo i, "C"
          Case Else
            WScript.Echo i, "D"
        End Select
        WScript.Echo i, "E"
        Exit Do
    Loop ' Jumper Loop
    WScript.Echo i, "F", "---------"
Next
```

output:

```
1 A
1 C
1 E
1 F ---------
2 A
2 B
2 F ---------
3 D
3 E
3 F ---------
```

Comment: You can change it to Loop While False to eliminate the need for the Exit Do at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Question is already answered, but just for your information you can use this construct (I took the condition `Apples = Pears` as your `If ... Then` condition):

```
Select Case True
    Case (Apples = Pears)
         ' Do nothing, so it just breaks out of the select construct
    Case (x = 1)
         Response.Write( ... )
    Case Else
         Response.Write( ... )
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

If you surround the select within a `do loop` then you can use `exit do` to get out of the select.

```
do
    select case i
        case 1
            ...do stuff...
        case 2
            ...do stuff...
        case 3
            exit do
        case else
            ...do stuff...
    end select
    exit do
loop
```

Note the `exit do` before the end of the `loop` because you don't want to actually loop.